# JScrollPane does not react to scrollRectToVisible

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have the following window:

```
public class MyWindows extends JFrame {


private final JScrollPane pane;

public MyWindows(){
    super();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    pane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);


    JButton left = new JButton("<");
    left.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            moveLeft();
        }
    });
    cp.add(left, BorderLayout.WEST);


    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
    for(int i = 1; i<20; i++) {
        panel.add(new JButton("hallo nummer "+i));
    }



    cp.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    JButton right = new JButton(">");
    cp.add(right, BorderLayout.EAST);

    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);



    pack();


    this.setSize(300, 100);

}

private void moveLeft() {
    Rectangle rec = pane.getVisibleRect();
    rec.setLocation((int)(rec.getX()+1000), (int)rec.getY());
    System.out.println(rec);
    pane.scrollRectToVisible(rec);
    System.out.println(pane.getVisibleRect());
}

}
```

[image: Screenshot of window]

The idea was to scroll along the buttons in the center, using the buttons on the left and on the right.

Unfortunately, the moveLeft()-Method does exactly nothing when it comes to scrolling.

The target-rectangle is java.awt.Rectangle[x=1000,y=0,width=202,height=61]

To me, that looks like a rectangle the ScrollPane should be able to scroll to.

What am I missing?

Also, sorry about the wall of code, but I just have no idea where the error may be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `scrollRectToVisible` method on desired component (`JPanel` in your case) but on `JScrollPane` object.

```
private JPanel panel;

...

private void moveLeft() {
    Rectangle rec = panel.getVisibleRect();
    rec.setLocation((int) (rec.getX() + 1000), (int) rec.getY());
    System.out.println(rec);
    panel.scrollRectToVisible(rec);
    System.out.println(panel.getVisibleRect());
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel a little blind and embarrassed now, should have seen that. :).